# Generating a dynamic parameter in Jenkins based off a parameter from the same job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameter-passing

I've got a Jenkins build with a choice box for build prefixes by release. It helps trigger a job based off the value of whatever specific build the person wanted.

I wanted to take the value of that choice box and transform the variable into the correct prefix based off the naming conventions typically used on this server for triggering the job based off its name.

So let's say I've got build prefix choices specifically for,
`ReleaseOne`
`ReleaseTwo`
`none`

For `none`, meaning the parameters used won't try to access or set any specific release-based info by triggering the non-release-specified build.

I wanted to take the value of `Release_Prefix` and transform it, if needed, for the job that I trigger later. I was hoping to accomplish this with a dynamic parameter or similar mechanism. I'm not sure if my script is bugged, or something fundamental is not working to my intent. This might be the case, based off some alluded feedback from a similar question.

Can I do something like this snippet below? If not with Dynamic Parameter plugin + GroovyScript, what would you suggest? This currently seems to return nothing, regardless of my choice.

`Formatted_Prefix` parameter, Dynamic Parameter

```
switch(binding.getVariables().get("Release_Prefix"))
{
    case "none":
        return "";
    case "ReleaseOne":
        return "ReleaseOne_";
    case "ReleaseTwo":
        return "ReleaseTwo_";
    default:
        def prefix = binding.getVariables().get("Release_Prefix")
        return "$prefix_";
}
```

There's multiple ways I can overcome this, but if I can do it at the initial parameter stage, that would be best for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EnvInject Plugin for this.

Check the checkbox **Prepare an environment for the run**  and
write your script inside **Evaluated Groovy script** text box

```
def prefix1 = Release_Prefix + "mydata"
return[prefix:prefix1]
```

Comment: Thanks! Just an FYI to anyone reading this answer -- this will not create a new _Jenkins_ variable, e.g., one that will show up in the environment variables, but this does work. I used the logic in this screenshot to help trigger builds based off known naming conventions that this server uses: http://i.imgur.com/Ibt0jT1.png -- the variable to reference in-job would be `${Formatted_Prefix}`, in bash, `$Formatted_Prefix`, in cmd, `%Formatted_Prefix%`